# Best solution for returning result from AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have an AsyncTask that receives a list of data from the internet. What is the best procedure for returning this list to the calling thread and add it to a Spinner?

Comment: Cannot the asynctask add to the spinner directly?

Comment: AsyncTask's onPostExecute() is allowed to work, to an extent, with your main UI so you can return what you need to from there like a normal method within your main ui class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a method in your calling thread which accepts the list as argument and adds it to the spinner. Then you can call this function from the `onPostExecute()` method.